# Codeigniter sending mail with empty content

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I'm using codeigniter email function for sending mail.
Here is the code.

```
 $this->email->to($to);     
 $this->email->subject($subject);
 $this->email->attach($_FILES['attachments']['tmp_name']);
 $this->email->message($mailcontent);
 if($this->email->send())
    {
    return true;
    }
```

when I printed the content just before sending it like this, I found its fine till there.

```
$this->email->message($mailcontent);
print_r($mailcontent);exit;
     if($this->email->send())
        {
        return true;
        }
```

But the mail I'm getting is empty.It has subject but the body is empty.
Why is this happening ?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @Niloy Saha.. I found that this happens when I tried to send mail without attachment.So I just put the code for adding attachment in an if condition and it worked.

```
if($_FILES['attachments']['tmp_name'])
{   
   $this->email->attach($_FILES['attachments']['tmp_name']);
}
$this->email->message($mailcontent);
if($this->email->send())
{
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly load the email library:

```
$this->load->library('email');
```

Secondly just after sending the mail check:

```
if($this->email->send()){
    echo $this->email->print_debugger();die;
}
```

Comment: I got the message as Unable to locate the following email attachment:
Your message has been successfully sent using the following protocol: mail   . So I tried with attachment and it works fine.So how can I get it work gud without attachment !

Comment: Write this line at the top: `$this->email->clear(TRUE);` just after loading the email library.

Comment: that didnt work.But when I give the attachment code in an if condition,it worked.

Comment: are you sending any attachment with the mail? re-post your code here or update your question.